# Two PPT Presentation is opening instead of one while running through VISUAL STUDIO 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint-2010

I am facing a problem but I am not able to carve out a solution. I have written a program in which a PowerPoint presentation with two slides is developed using C#. When I run the program everything is working fine but an extra blank PowerPoint presentation is also created (`Presentation2.pptx`). I am not able to understand why a blank presentation is created. Please help me through this.

Below is my code:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=****;Password=******");

        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PowerPointTest", con);

        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

        da.Fill(ds);
        PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide1;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;

        // Create the Presentation File
        PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

        // Create new Slide
        slides = pptPresentation.Slides;
        slide = slides.AddSlide(1, customLayout);
        slide1 = slides.AddSlide(2, customLayout);
        slide.ApplyTheme(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Austin.thmx");
        slide1.ApplyTheme(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Austin.thmx");
        // Add title
        objText = slide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
        objText.Text = "test";
        objText.Font.Name = "Arial";
        objText.Font.Size = 32;

        objText = slide1.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
        objText.Text = "TEST1";
        objText.Font.Name = "Arial";
        objText.Font.Size = 40;

        objText = slide.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange;
        string Username = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"]);
        string LoginID = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["LoginID"]);
        string EmailID1 = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmailID1"]);
        objText.Text = "UserName:" + Username +"\n LoginID:"+ LoginID +"\n Email ID:"+EmailID1+".";



        objText = slide1.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange;
        objText.Text = "Content goes from here\nYou cannot add text\nItem 3";
        objText.Font.Size = 24;


        slide.NotesPage.Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test";

        pptPresentation.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\test.pptx", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get you. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Add-In project for Office applications, your `ThisAddIn` class will have a field called `Application`<sup>1</sup> which is the running `Application` object for the Office Application. You should use this to interact with the running application rather than having this line:

```
PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();
```

That is, you should delete this line and replace any uses of `pptApplication` with just `Application`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The field isn't visible in the `.cs` file but you should be able to see it in Intellisense or  by expanding Solution Explorer:

[image]

Comment: I commented the line :

PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();

and in place of 

PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

I changed it to

PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

but still two ppt file is opening after I run the program.